# dual space of the subspace of the space of probability measures

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a question which maybe so naive but I want to know the result about it.

Let $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of bounded measures. Then by some materiau such as Multidimensional diffusion processes and Large deviations, we know that the dual space of $\mathcal{M}$ is $\mathcal{C}_b^0(\mathbb{R})$ which is the space of continuous bounded functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Here the topology of $\mathcal{M}$ is induced by weak convergence.

Now we consider a subspace $\mathcal{M}_p$ of $\mathcal{M}$ such that:

$$\mathcal{M}_p=\{\mu\in\mathcal{M}: \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2\mu(dx)<\infty\}$$

I would like to know the dual space of $\mathcal{M}_p$, I guess it is the space of continuous functions $f$ satisfying

$$|f(x)|\leq C(1+|x|^2)$$

for some constant $C$. But I don't know how to prove it. If someone knows it please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The notion of **dual**  is usually associated to a vector space. The space of probability measures  is not a vector space.

Comment: There is probably a sensible question to be asked, but this should be "put on hold" until CodeGolf repairs it.

Comment: Since every (Borel) probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a weak limit of linear combinations of Dirac measures (which all have finite second moment), isn't the closure of $\mathcal{M}_p$ in the topology of weak convergence $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: Thanks for Liviu for the comments, but in general for a locally convex space, we can define its dual space and for more details : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenchel%E2%80%93Moreau_theorem

Comment: I try to show $\mathcal{M}_p$ is closed under the weak convergence on $\mathcal{M}$, but I think it is not true

Comment: Since for any $\{\mu_n\}\subset\mathcal{M}_p$ converging to $\mu$ for the weak convergence, we need to show that $\mu\in\mathcal{M}_p$

Comment: By some theorem, there exists a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ converging a.s. to $X$, which are defined on some probability space, and $X_n$ has the law $\mu_n$ and $X$ has the law $\mu$.

Comment: But $X_n$ being square integrable and $X_n\rightarrow X$ can not ensure $X$ is also square integrable, thus $\mathcal{M}_p$ is not closed

Comment: Thanks for the question of Chris, I believe that the answer is yes. But how can we find the dual space of $\mathcal{M}_p$ if we know $\mathcal{M}_p$'s closure is $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: These are signed measures?  So we can have $\int x^2 \mu(dx) = 0$ for nontrivial $\mu$?  Perhaps you want a "norm" defined as $\int x^2 |\mu|(dx)$ ?

Comment: Well in a Banach space, it is easy to show that a bounded linear functional on a dense set extends to the entire space, so your dual space would have to be the same as the dual space of $\mathcal{M}$.  This is because continuity of a linear functional in a Banach space is the same as Lipschitz continuity and Lipschitz maps take Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.  I honestly do not even know the definition of the dual space of something other than a vector space, so maybe it's more complicated there.

Comment: As pointed out above, the question is not well posed, not least becuase the linear span of the points measures is dense on the bounded measures for its natural topologz (not the norm, of course).  However, there is an interpretation for which there is a sensible answer and maybe this is what the OP was after.  There is a natural complete topology on the space of bounded, continuous functions on the line for which the dual space is the space of bounded measures and the dualitz is symmetrical.  This is the strict topology which was introduced by R.C. Buck in the 50's

Comment: using weighted seminorrms.  Similarly, there is such a topology on the space of continuous functions which grow like $x^2$ and such that the dual is the space of measures which satisfy the growth conditions zou are implying. For the record, in the first case you use as weights the continuous functions which vanish at infinity, in the the second one those for which $(1+x^2) f(x)$ does so.

Comment: The topology that User4891 is talking about is commonly known as 2-Wasserstein convergence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric).

Comment: @AlexanderShamov. no, it's not.

Comment: @User4891: Sorry for that. The Wasserstein convergence is the right analogue of weak convergence for measures with moments. Did you mean something stronger instead, like the Mackey topology?

Comment: I am now a bit confused about what topology we are talking about but the strict topology is, in the case of the real line (even for a $\sigma$-compact, locally compact space), indeed the Mackey topology.  This is a not completely trivial fact.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is any locally convex space and $L$ is a subspace (endowed with the relative topology) then the (continuous) dual $L'$ of $L$ is a *quotient* of $X'$ by the subspace $L^\perp=\lbrace f\in X': f|_L=0\rbrace$
(this follows from Hahn-Banach: the restriction map $X' \to L'$ is surjective).

Even if you modify the definition of $\mathcal M_p$ as suggested by Gerald Edgar
there is thus no reason to expect $\mathcal M_p'$ to be a  *subspace* of $\mathcal M'$.

Comment: Would it be a quotient space then?